# print one column header in italics

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas to make an HTML table. I want one of my column headers to be in italics. I can put the whole of a header row in italics like this:

```
import pandas as pd
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["", "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                                 ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["first", 20, 30, 50, 80],
                        ["second", 30, 40, 90, 20],],
                 columns=col, 
                 )
df_styled = df.style.hide(axis="index")
df_styled.set_table_styles([
    {'selector': 'th.col_heading.level1', 'props': 'font-style: italic;'},
], overwrite=False)
```

[image: picture of output]

How do I put just one of the column headers ("b", say) in italics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the [physical position](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#CSS-Classes-and-Ids) (`col<n>`) of column `"b"` in the CSS selector :

```
df_styled.set_table_styles(
    [
        {
            "selector": "th.col_heading.level1.col1", # << here
            "props": "font-style: italic;",
        },
    ],
    overwrite=False,
)
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can set table styles by defining a list of styles for all columns or one column at a time:

```
import pandas as pd

col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["", "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                                 ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["first", 20, 30, 50, 80],
                        ["second", 30, 40, 90, 20],],
                 columns=col, 
                 )

df_styled = df.style.hide(axis="index")

# Set the header "b" in italics
df_styled.set_table_styles([
    {'selector': 'th.col_heading.level1', 'props': 'font-style: normal;'},
    {'selector': 'th.col_heading.level1.col1', 'props': 'font-style: italic;'},
], overwrite=False)

# Display the styled DataFrame
df_styled
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifically target that header with a unique identifier in the CSS. Since Pandas doesn't directly support individual header styling through the style method, you'd typically use a workaround by injecting HTML directly into the column name or using external CSS and JavaScript for web display.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
["", "one", "one", "two", "two"],
["a", "<i>b</i>", "c", "d", "e"]])    
df_styled = df.style.hide(axis="index")
```